# AWS Amplify: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm setting up aws-amplify to my project. I am facing a problem in amplify push when I configured for the first time it worked fine. now i changed the repository since i had to do sub-tree from the old repo.
Now when i do amplify push i get

Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete

⠸ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...Error updating cloudformation stack
⠸ Updating resources in the cloud. This may take a few minutes...

Following resources failed

✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
An error occured during the push operation: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete

Comment: I would recommend upgrade amplify-cli version and try again

Comment: No, I've fixed it. The problem was in the cloud formation template. Reverted the cloud formation template and also updated auth using amplify auth update.

Comment: I updated my api key which had an expiraration date long overdue. then it worked out fine

Comment: @Beki how did you update the api key?

Answer (score 30):

Just to give some background about this error - what does `Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete` actually mean?

Well basically Amplify is telling you that one of the stacks in your app did not deploy correctly, but it doesn't know why (which is remarkably unhelpful, but in fairness it's deploying a lot of potentially complex resources).

This can make diagnosing and fixing the issue really problematic, so I've compiled this kind of mental checklist that I go through to fix it. Each of the techniques will work *some* of the time, but I don't think there are any that will work *all* of the time. This list is not intended to help you diagnose what causes this issue, it's literally just designed to get you back up and running.

### The fast options (will solve most problems)

- **Check the AWS Console**! Sometimes the amplify-cli will show an error, but it actually did what you asked it to in the cloud. Before proceeding, always check to make sure the error was actually fatal.
- If you're sure your deployment is definitely failing, then next step is to *MAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR LOCAL WORK* before proceeding with any of the following steps.
- Firstly, you can try to restore your env from the one in the last working deployment in the cloud by running `amplify env pull --restore`.
- Try running `amplify push --iterative-rollback`. It's supposed to roll your environment back to the last successful deployment, but tbh it rarely works.
- Try running `amplify push --force`. Although counter-intuitive, this is actually a rollback method. It basically does what you think `--iterative-rollback` will do, but works more frequently.
- In the AWS console, go to the deployment bucket for your environment (the bucket will be named `amplify-${project_name}-${environment_name}-${some_random_numbers}-deployment`). If there is a file called `deployment-state.json`, delete it and try `amplify push` again from the CLI.
- If you are working in a team of more than one developer, or have your environment in several different repos locally, or across multiple different machines, your `amplify/team-provider-info.json` file might be out of sync. Usually this is caused by the environment variable(s) in an Amplify Lambda function being set in one of the files but not in another. The resolution will depend on how out of sync these files are, but you can normally just copy the contents of the last working `team-provider-info.json` file across to the other repo (from where the deployment is failing) and run the deployment again. However, if you've got multiple devs/machines/repos, you might be better off diffing the files and checking where the differences are.
- If any of these worked, you can then re-add the any changes that were lost by diffing your repo again the backup you made and copying the changes back over.

### The slow option (production-friendly)

Hopefully you haven't got this far, but at this point I'd recommend you open a ticket in the [amplify-cli GitHub](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli) with as much info as you can. They tend to respond in 1-2 working days.

If you're pre-production, or you're having issues with a non-production environment, you could also try cloning the backend environment in the Amplify console, and seeing if you can get the stack working from there. If so, then you can push the fixed deployment back to the previous env (if you want to) using `amplify env checkout ${your_old_env_name}` and then `amplify push`.

### The complex option (solves more intricate problems with your stack)

If none of the above work (or you don't have time to wait for a response on a GitHub issue), head over to CloudFormation in the AWS console and search for the part of your stack that is erroring. There's a few different ways to do this:

1. Check the CLI output for your last push and find the item whose status is something **other than** `UPDATE_COMPLETE`. You can copy the name of the stack and search for it in CloudFormation.
2. Search CloudFormation for your environment name, click on any of the resulting stacks, click the link under `Parent stack`, repeat until you find a stack with no parent. You are now in the root stack of your deployment, there are two ways to find your erroring stack from here:

   - Click on the `Resources` tab and find one with something red in the status column. Select the stack from this row.
   - Click on the `Events` tab and find one with something red in the status column. Select the stack from this row.
3. Once you've found the broken stack, click the `Stack actions` button and select `Detect drift` from the dropdown menu.
4. Click the `Stack actions` button again and select `View drift results` from the dropdown menu.
5. In the `Resource drift results` page, you'll see a list of resources in the stack. If any of them show `DRIFTED` in the `Drift status` column, select the radio button to the left of that item and then click the `View drift details` button. The drift details will be displayed side by side, git-style, on the next page. You can also click the checkbox(es) in the list above to highlight the drift change(s). **Keep the current page open, you'll need it later**.
6. Fixing the drift will depend on what it is - it's usually something in an IAM policy that's changed, you can fix this directly in the console. Sometimes it's a missing environment variable on a Lambda function, which you're better off fixing in the CLI (in which case you would need to run `amplify push` again and wait for the build to complete in order for the fix to be deployed to your environment).
7. Once you've fixed the drift, you can click the orange `Detect stack drift` button at the top of the page and it will update. Hopefully you've solved the problem.

### GraphQL bonus round (completely bananas DDB drift)

Another fun thing that Amplify does from time-to-time is to (seemingly spontaneously) change the server-side encryption setting on the definition of some or all of your DynamoDB tables without you even touching it. This is by far and away the most bizarre Amplify error I've encountered (and that's saying something)!

I have a *sort-of* fix for this, which is to open `amplify/backend/api/${your_api_name}/parameters.json` and change the `DynamoDBEnableServerSideEncryption` setting from `false` to `true`, save it, then run `amplify push`. This will fail. But it's fine, because then you just reverse the change (set it back to `false`), save it, push again and voila! I still cannot for the life of me understand how or why this happens.

I said it's a *sort-of* fix, and that's because you'll still see drift for the stacks that deploy the affected tables in CloudFormation. This goes away after a while. Again, I have no idea how or why.

### The nuclear option (DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION)

***Obviously this one comes with a huge disclaimer: don't do this in production. If working with any kind of DB, you will lose the data.***

You can make backups of everything and then start to remove the problematic resources one at a time, with an `amplify push` in between each one, until the stack build successfully. Once it's built, you can start adding your resources back in.

Hopefully this helps someone, please feel free to suggest edits or other solutions.

Comment: I'd like to buy you ☕️

Comment: Worked with a failing api update.

Comment: @webjay thank you for the offer. I don't drink coffee, but I do support charities. If you could make a donation to mind.org.uk for the equivalent amount that would be amazing! ☕️

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  My only suggestion would be to start with `amplify env pull --restore`.  Unless you think that would be destructive it seems to be the most reliable (I just had to save my GQL Schema changes and re-apply them).

Comment: Thanks @ZekeTheGeek I've updated the answer based on your feedback.

Comment: My root Cloudformation stack was in a `COMPLETE` state and one of its nested stacks failed. I was unable to fix my issue with any of these steps (except the nuclear option). I followed [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/continue-update-rollback.html) on ONLY the nested stack that was in the `UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED` state and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

`$ amplify update auth`

Choose the option “Yes, use default configuration” (uses the Cognito Identitypool).

Then:

`$ amplify push`

Another reason can be [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/2096#issuecomment-523746110)

> The issue is tied to the selection of this option - Select the authentication/authorization services that you want to use: `User Sign-Up & Sign-In only (Best used with a cloud API only)` which creates just the UserPool and not the IdentityPool which the rootstack is looking for. It's a bug and we'll fix that.
>
> To unblock, for just the first question, you could select - ❯ `User
>   Sign-Up, Sign-In, connected with AWS IAM controls (Enables per-user
>   Storage features for images or other content, Analytics, and more)`
>   which would create a user pool as well as as the identity pool and
>   then choose any of the other configurations that you've mentioned
>   above.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

a. Go to the s3 bucket containing project settings.

b. locate `deployment-state.json` file in root folder and delete it.

c. `amplify push`

Answer (score 3):

I debugged my AWS Amplify CLI push error by doing the following:

1. Open `CloudFormation`
2. Find parent stack with name such as: `amplify-companyName-envName-123456`
3. Click `Events` tab
4. Scroll down until you find `UPDATE_FAILED`, which should give you a detailed description of why it failed. e.g. `The following resource(s) failed to create: ...`

Alternatively (to find parent stack):

1. Navigate to environment in AWS Amplify site, `Overview` tab
2. Click `View in CloudFormation`
3. Under `Stack info` tab, click link for `Parent stack`
4. On the parent page, click `Events` tab

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below

First do

`amplify env checkout {environment}` and then

`amplify push`

Comment: This is what actually caused my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
amplify remove storage
```

And, then

```
amplify add storage
```

Then, again

```
amplify push
```

As after `amplify add storage` I mistakenly choose Y to Do you want to add a Lambda Trigger for your S3 Bucket?
I didn't have any Lamda function and also I didn't have anything in my bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I got this after making some modifications to my GraphQL schema. I adjusted the way I was making @connection directives on a few tables. I was able to fix this by following these steps:-

1. Make a backup copy of your new schema that you're trying to push
2. Run  `amplify pull` to restore your local to be in sync with your backend in the cloud.
3. Once that completes, you should have the local synced to the cloud and `amplify push` should work without flaws because it is synced to the cloud and there should be no updates.
4. Copy over the new schema onto the pulled schema and try running the `amplify push` once more to see if it works.

If it doesn't work, undo the overwrite to the pulled schema and compare what is different between the pulled schema and the updated schema that you backed up.  Do a line by line diffcheck and see what has changed and try to push the changes one by one to see where it is failing. I think it is wiser to not push too many changes to the schema at once. Do it one by one so that you can troubleshoot more easily. If you do have other issues, then it should be unrelated to the one highlighted in this question, because the pulling should solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was due to multiple `@connections` referring to GSI, which were not getting removed and added correctly when I do the amplify push api.

I was able to resolve this by `amplify pull` then, comment off the `@connection` then the GSI linked to connection then, add each new changes manually, but there was trouble in GSI getting linked again because the local update considered the GSI already removed but in cloud it seems to be retained, and I got error that a GSI is being added which was already in cloud. So I renamed the model name, so it got recreated to new tables in dynamoDB then I reverted it back to the correct name. This is ideal for dev environment which has no much impact.

But of course it ate up most of my time, but it did fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue when switching between amplify env (checkout), the error was not clear but this is what I did to fix it without having to "clear" api and lose the whole database :

- Delete the existing API Key by setting the "CreateAPIKey" to "0" in the "amplify/backend/api//parameters.json" then save file and execute "amplify push".
- once done, do the same process with "CreateAPIKey" to "1" then "amplify push".
  This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below steps and it worked for me:

1. amplify init
   ? Do you want to use an existing environment? Yes
   ? Choose the environment you would like to use: dev
2. amplify push

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what worked for me -
I was getting the same error while deploying and it was because of one rest api that wasn't working.
I deleted all the resources related to REST and created one GraphQL API and use that instead.
After that, I ran this command - `amplify push --force`
and then pushed the update code to repository. Build Succeeded.**

Although, I got to know where the error is when I ran `amplify push --force`

Here are general cases that may be helpful for you.
The error message "AWS Amplify: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete" typically occurs when there is an issue with the update or deployment of a resource in AWS Amplify. This error indicates that the resource you are trying to update or deploy is not in the expected state, specifically the "stackUpdateComplete" state.

To troubleshoot this issue, you can take the following steps:

1. Verify Amplify configuration: Ensure that your Amplify project configuration is correct and up to date. Check the project configuration files (e.g., `amplify/team-provider-info.json`) and make sure they reflect the desired state of your resources.
2. Check for incomplete deployments: If there was a previous deployment that encountered an error or was interrupted, it can result in resources being left in an incomplete state. Use the Amplify CLI commands such as `amplify status` or `amplify console` to check the status of your resources and identify any incomplete deployments.
3. Retry the deployment: If the resource is indeed not in the expected state, you can try retrying the deployment. Use the Amplify CLI command `amplify push` to initiate the deployment process again and allow Amplify to update or create the necessary resources.
4. Review logs and error messages: Check the Amplify deployment logs and error messages for more specific details about the failure. The logs can provide additional insights into the cause of the issue and help you determine the necessary steps to resolve it.
5. Check AWS service status: Occasionally, AWS services may experience disruptions or issues that can affect resource deployments. Visit the AWS Service Health Dashboard or the Amplify Status page to check if there are any known service disruptions or incidents that could be impacting your deployment.

If the issue persists after following these steps, it might be helpful to reach out to AWS support or the Amplify support team for further assistance. Provide them with the specific error message and any relevant logs to help them investigate and troubleshoot the issue more effectively.

Comment: Where did you copy all this text from? Is it AI generated? ChatGPT and its brethren are banned on Stack Overflow. You should delete this.  We take plagiarism seriously here.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, these kind of problems always related to 3rd party auth.

- Amplify update auth,
- then update auth flow the id and secret of 3rd party.
- Then push.

It will fix the problem

Comment: They relate to a poorly made product by AWS. Why I have to recreate everything all of the sudden, to fix this ?!

Comment: The reality is that this error comes up for a whole host of reasons. The error feedback in Amplify is less than fantastic.

Answer (score -2):

It's look like a conflict between backend and local

The only thing that work for me is backing up the local schema and initiating the amplify pulling command.

Then use the back up schema file and initial the amplify push.

In most of case updates in the following file must be set manually (for Android):
app/src/main/res/raw/amplifyconfiguration.json

Comment: Oras asked this question in the Amplify CLI GitHub repository, as well. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6012

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned by others in this thread - the issue comes from one of the resources that you updated locally.

Check which ones did you modify:

```
$ amplify status
```

Then `remove` and `add` it again, followed by `push`. The `Api` is known not to work with updates right now, so you must remove it if you've changed it locally:

```
$ amplify api remove YourAPIName
$ amplify api add
$ amplify push
```

Comment: It should be noted that this would erase any data that you may have in your tables. Not recommended for production of course!

Comment: This should be a negative answer... how are you going to recommend people to remove the api lol