# "amplify push function" error: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Here's what I do:

1. `amplify add function` (...and then go through the wizard in order to create a serverless function...);
2. `amplify push`;

And, boom! Here's what I get

> × An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud  An
> error occurred during the push operation: / Resource is not in the
> state stackUpdateComplete

In the s3 bucket, I can see that the function zip file got created under /amplify-builds.

Oh, and before you ask, I've found no deployment-state.json file at the root level.

CloudFormation tells me that resource update failed because of:

> Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:::stack/amplify----api-/ was
> not successfully updated. Currently in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS
> with reason: The following resource(s) failed to update:
> [GraphQLAPITransformerSchema3CB2AE18].

I've tried `amplify remove function` followed by `amplify add function` without significant result.

The error log file doesn't really help either:

```
{
    "message": "Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete",
    "code": "ResourceNotReady",
    "retryable": false,
    "time": "2022-07-15T16:49:21.011Z",
    "statusCode": 200,
    "retryDelay": 30000
}
```

Where should I go from here?

Comment: have you had any luck solving this issue or is it still ongoing?

Comment: See this forum for a detailed explanation and plenty of alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168051/aws-amplify-resource-is-not-in-the-state-stackupdatecomplete

Answer (score 0):

You should go CloudFormation UI directly, find this resource and select "Stack Actions" in top right corner. You will see buttons "Continue" or "Cancel" update stack. After this actions "amplify push" should work

Comment: The options are not 'enabled' for me